# jQuery modal popup confirm - handle server side postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to run a modal popup for a confirm message after clicking an asp:Button control. I'm using the tutorial from http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/ as a base.

Currently I have the client side action working and the modal popup coming up with my message and confirm buttons.

The problem I'm having is with setting the doPostBack for the yes button:

```
 __doPostBack([button I want to target], '');
```

I've tried to use:

```
<%=this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(this.Button123))%>;
```

for the doPostBack command to find the button control. The problem with this method is, it's firing the postback before I have an option to load the modal.

Using the hardcoded doPostBack that is returned from the above "GetPostBackEventReference"

```
 __doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$Button123', '');
```

I Am able to postback to the proper server onClick event after clicking yes in the modal.

I would like to know how to use the ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference method and not postback before showing the modal or an alternative to this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button123" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="Ctl_ButtonUpdateRecord_Click" />

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[id$='Button123']").click(function () {

        $.confirm({
            'title': 'Delete Confirmation',
            'message': 'You are about to delete this item. <br />It cannot be restored at a later time! Continue?',
            'buttons': {
                'Yes': {
                    'class': 'blue',
                    'action': function () { <%=this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(this.Button123))%>;
                                             //__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$Button123', '');
                                             }
                },
                'No': {
                    'class': 'gray'
                }
            }
        });

        return false;

    });

});

(function ($) {

    $.confirm = function (params) {

        if ($('#confirmOverlay').length) {
            // A confirm is already shown on the page:
            return false;
        }

        var buttonHTML = '';
        $.each(params.buttons, function (name, obj) {

            // Generating the markup for the buttons:

            buttonHTML += '<a href="#" class="button ' + obj['class'] + '">' + name + '<span></span></a>';

            if (!obj.action) {
                obj.action = function () { };
            }
        });

        var markup = [
            '<div id="confirmOverlay">',
            '<div id="confirmBox">',
            '<h1>', params.title, '</h1>',
            '<p>', params.message, '</p>',
            '<div id="confirmButtons">',
            buttonHTML,
            '</div></div></div>'
        ].join('');

        $(markup).hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn();

        var buttons = $('#confirmBox .button'),
            i = 0;

        $.each(params.buttons, function (name, obj) {
            buttons.eq(i++).click(function () {

                // Calling the action attribute when a
                // click occurs, and hiding the confirm.

                obj.action();
                $.confirm.hide();
                return false;
            });
        });
    }

    $.confirm.hide = function () {
        $('#confirmOverlay').fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to use the ModalPopup provided by ajaxtoolkit. [Here a sample.](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)

Or you could also do this:

```
'action': function () { $('#<%= btnDelete.ClientID %>').click(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are doing everything correct, I've just tried it like so, and it works fine:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Test" onclick="btnDelete_Click" style="display: none" />
<input type="submit" value="Test" id="Button123">
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[id$='Button123']").click(function () {

        $.confirm({
            'title': 'Delete Confirmation',
            'message': 'You are about to delete this item. <br />It cannot be restored at a later time! Continue?',
            'buttons': {
                'Yes': {
                    'class': 'blue',
                    'action': function() { <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(btnDelete))%>; }
                },
                'No': {
                    'class': 'gray'
                }
            }
        });

        return false;

    });

});

</script>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I am having issues with using these scripts on external files. I am able to run the server side script directly on the page, but cannot run it in an external .js file.

Comment: You will not be able to properly execute the `Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference` directive inside an external JavaScript file as it will not be `processed` in the same way as `asp.net` page. The only thing you can do is to include this part directly on your page.

Answer (score 0):

I carry ou a simple piece of code that I hope can help you. In the example I used the JQuery UI Dialog Widget (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) that you can also customize.

Script Code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function ConfirmDelete(controId, arg) {
        var $dialogConfirmDelete = $('<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are you sure you want delete the record?</p>')
        .dialog({
            title: 'Title',
            resizable: false,
            height: 160,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                'OK': function () {
            __doPostBack(controId, '');
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    $($dialogConfirmDelete).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));

        return $dialogConfirmDelete.dialog(arg);
    }

    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        ConfirmDelete(null);
    })

</script>
```

ASPX code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteRecord" runat="server" Text="Delete record"  OnClientClick="javascript:ConfirmDelete(this.name,'open');return false;"  onclick="btnDeleteRecord_Click" />
```

C# Code Behind:

```
/// <summary>
/// delete record
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void btnDeleteRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Delete record
    //...
}
```

Remember that the framework add, to web controls like asp: buttons, linkbuttons, DropDownLists, etc., the section of code that handle the postback only if the property "**AutoPostBack**" is set to "**true**".
You can also entering the following simple statement in the code behind (eg. in the Page_Load ()):
`ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink (btnDeleteRecord, "");`
What skills to run the postback control ();